# Linear Dependence problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets suppose we have a set of vectors  $\{(1 ,0, 0, 0 ) , (0, 1, 0, 0 ), (2, 0, 0, 0 )\}$.

By definition this set is linearly dependent because we can find constants $c_1,c_2, c_3$ ( such that all are not $0$ at the same time ) that satisfy this equation :

Equation1-     c1.(1 0 0 0) + c2(0 1 0 0) + c3(2 0 0 0) = 0

I also learned that in a linearly dependent set, every vetor can be generated by the linear combination of the others.

This doesn't hold in this case and the reason is probabily because c2 must be 0 to satisfy Equation 1, so we can't isolate (0 1  0 0) in function of the other vectors in Equation1.

What's the conclusion ? I need to forget that i learned that in a linearly dependent set, every vetor can be generated by the linear combination of the others ?
Is there any other insight you guys can give me ?

Thanks

Comment: Its **not** every vector in your collection, its any vector in your collection is written in terms of other vectors then its a linear dependent vectors

Comment: Man, i think you hit straigth to the point ?

Comment: That's not accurate either, Learner: a set of vector is linearly *dependent* iff there's one of the vectors in it can be written as a linear combination of other vectors there. If the set of vectors can be well ordered, then we can sharpen this: a set of vectors is lin. dep. iff there is one vector that is a linear comb. of the *preceding* ones

Comment: DonAntonio , isn't what Learner said "Its not every vector in your collection, its any vector in your collection is written in terms of other vectors " exactly equal to what you said " a set of vector is lienarly dependent iff there one of the vectors in it can be writtent as a linear combination of other vectors there" ? I'm confused

Comment: every$\not=$ there's one:)

Comment: @Nerdy, as I understand the english grammar in that sentence, *any* means *every*, and then it is wrong. Perhaps more accurate would be "some".

Comment: True, but learned probabily didnt write "any" with the "every" meaning since he had already said that "Its not every vector"

Comment: Good point, @nerdy: he probably meant that, though it came out with a different meaning.

Comment: I can even close the topic now hehe thanks for the quick insights

Answer (score 0):

[Please don't up vote: just summarising comments so question not in unanswered state forever]

A linearly independent set means **no** vector in the set can be expressed as a linear combination of the others.

A linearly dependent set means **at least one** of the vectors can be expressed as a linear combination of the others. Please forget the faulty definition that "every vector can be expressed as a linear combination of the others"!